# regex 'literal' meaning in regex

Tags: c#, .net, regex

is there a way to treat a section of your regex string 'as is'?

I.e. I want to match for the literal pattern: "[^*..@/w$[{" in some text (exaggerated example, but you see what I mean)... Can I just enclose the whole bit in something?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `Regex.Escape`.
See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.escape.aspx